# google maps tracks api - send request using node js

Tags: node.js, google-maps

In order to access the google maps tracks API, i have access token sent by Google’s OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server. Now i need to send this access token with every http request i made to google map tracks API. Where should i put this access token in http request ?. I tried to put in headers as 'X-Access-Token' : 'myaccesstoken', but am getting response from api as below.

**body: '{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "required",\n    "message": "Login Required",\n    "locationType": "header",\n    "location": "Authorization"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 401,\n  "message": "Login Required"\n }\n}\n' }**

I referred google map tracks API official documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/auth, but unable to solve this error.

below is the code am using to authenticate with Google’s OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server, and code to send request to google map tracks API.

```
var jwt = new googleapis.auth.JWT(client_email, keyFile, null, scopes, null);

jwt.authorize(function(jwtErr, tokens){
    if(jwtErr){
        return;
    }
    else{
        headers = {
            'content-type' : 'application/json',
            'X-Access-Token' : tokens.access_token
        };

        options = {
            url : 'https://www.googleapis.com/tracks/v1/geofences/list',
            headers : headers,
            method : 'POST',
        };
        request(options, function(error, response, body){
            if(error){
                return; 
            }
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, access token should be put in 
header : { 'Authorization' : 'myaccesstoken' },
so after changes, code will look like below.

```
var jwt = new googleapis.auth.JWT(client_email, keyFile, null, scopes, null);

jwt.authorize(function(jwtErr, tokens){
    if(jwtErr){
        return;
    }
    else{
        headers = {
            'content-type' : 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'content-length': Buffer.byteLength(data),
            **'Authorization' : tokens.access_token**
        };

        options = {
            host: 'www.googleapis.com',
            path: '/tracks/v1/entities/create',
            headers : headers,
            method : 'POST',
        };

        var post_req = https.request(options, function(res){
              res.setEncoding('utf8');
              res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                  console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
              });
        });
        post_req.on('error', function(error_msg){
            console.log(error_msg);
        });
        post_req.write(data);
        post_req.end();
    }
});
```